# R Studio Quitting Session Failure on Mac

Tags: force-quit

I have problems quitting R studio on Macbook Air after working tirelessly for over 12 hours and a large dataset. May I get help because my computer wont shut down now?

Comment: The normal way is to do a force quit from the Dock on RStudio - if you are asking how to save your data -well I think you are out of luck

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!